# How to upload python packages to my own Pypi server?

Tags: python, django, pypi

I am in a intranet environment and I have to setup my own pypi server for pip install. I got the server running but don't know how to upload packages to the server.

I read the documentation and here is what I think I should do:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/django/django.git  
$ cd django  
$ python setup.py sdist upload -r local
```

Is this correct?

Also, where can I find django's dependencies?

Comment: Why upload to your own server, when you can just use `pip install git+ssh<your git url here>`? The only requirement is that the root folder has to have the `setup.py` file in there.

Comment: because the machine is behind firewall and cannot access the outside world

Comment: pip supports [local project paths](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#usage)